# Using the CIDER debugger with Integrant

Tags: clojure, cider

I'm using [integrant](https://github.com/weavejester/integrant) in my application, and have code like such:

```
(defmethod ig/init-key :handler [_ {:keys [magic]}]
  (fn [req]
    (magic req)))
```

I've tried various ways to instrument the inner function for debugging with [cider](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/blob/master/doc/debugging.md), but cannot seem to get it to work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

what i do is create a function that the init calls and then instrument that function.  not perfect but at least I can break in it.